# what is MVVM, and should we use it?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, design-patterns, knockout.js

I've been looking at the MVVM pattern, specifically knockoutjs, and mostly it just makes me cringe. I won't go on a long rant about the benefits of keeping structure, presentation and display separate, I'll just ask (as an example): What's the difference between

```
<button data-bind="click: someJavaScriptFunction">Something</button>
```

and

```
<button onclick="someJavaScriptFunction();">Something</button>
```

and should we be putting so much behavior control into the markup? As clean and as minimalistic as this is, it seems to go against every web programming tenet I've ever heard about.

Am I wrong?

Comment: i've always been of the belief that you should try not have more than one language in a single file. typically I set an id or class and bind the function to it after the page has finished building though.

Comment: Seems the issue here is less about MVVM and more about the pros/cons of Unobtrusive JavaScript: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @Craig Having that data-bind in the markup doesn't seem in the spirit of unobtrusive js, so I'm not sure that's really what this is about.

Comment: I don't like the first example: it's kind of pretending not to be code when really it effectively is so why not just put the actual code like in the second example. Though for comparison you should have a third example where the events are not embedded in the HTML at all. I don't even like MVVM in C# WPF, so there's no way you'd get me using it with JavaScript.

Comment: References: 1) [Understanding MVVM – A Guide For JavaScript Developers](http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/)  2) [MVVM in Kendo UI Walkthrough](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/mvvm-in-kendo-ui) 3) [Build Single Page Apps – Part 7 – MVVM and KnockoutJS](http://www.johnpapa.net/spapost7/)

Comment: More references- 1) [MVVM using Kendo UI in three simple steps](http://telerikhelper.net/2013/08/09/mvvm-using-kendo-ui-in-three-simple-steps/)
2) [Kendo UI Web MVVM](http://blog.longle.net/2012/07/28/teleriks-kendo-ui-web-mvvm-framework-rocks/)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more direct answer to your question.

In the second example, you are referring to a function that has to be in the global scope (i.e. a property of the `window` object).

In the first example, you are referring to a property of the current view model.

Yes, it's a subtle distinction, but it is an important one. If you use on-event attributes you can only refer to things that exist in the global scope. This means you have to put everything you want to access in the global scope, which leads to very messy code.

If you use declarative bindings, the exact meaning of the bindings instead depends on the context.

It helps to think about the HTML markup as more coincidental. What you are really looking at is structured access to the view model. Think of `with` and `forEach` as nested contexts and of the other bindings as their attributes. The relationship between the declarative bindings and the underlying HTML suddenly feels more like working with XSLT.

The two examples *look* very similar. But the underlying concepts are vastly different and are what makes data binding so powerful and on-event attributes so obnoxious.

The reason on-event attributes are frowned upon isn't just that they mix logic with structure. It's that they're a weak attempt to bolt arbitrary JavaScript code to HTML elements which prevents proper encapsulation of application logic. On-event attributes are low-level "hooks", bindings extend the behaviour of elements.

All that said, it is likely possible to do the same horrible things people have done with on-event attributes by using declarative bindings. The difference is in what else you can do with them. You shouldn't always judge technologies by how they can be abused -- we're all adults here.

Comment: FWIW, you likely won't find bindings terribly useful outside of single-page applications (read: web apps that heavily rely on JavaScript). They could be useful to bind simple widgets like datepickers, but it's hard to find a use case for normal websites that couldn't be easily replicated with CSS selectors and jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Alan. That distinction makes a lot of sense. +1

Comment: But doesn't the scope of the called javascript have more to do with how you organize your script than whether or not it should exist in the markup. I could just as easily do something like (to use a common jQuery syntax) onclick="$(this).data('myplugin').someFunction()" to call a scoped function using the onclick handler.

Comment: My view is still that the markup is for data display and defining structure, scripts are for data manipulation and behavior, and css for styling. And those three should be as loosely coupled as possible. I'm loving data binding (and knockout specifically) to keep the DOM out of my data manipulation scripts, leaving me free to mess about my VM without worrying about how that data is displayed. But I still not convinced putting behavior handlers in the markup is worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Your only using one part of MVVM - specifically the View - in that code example you gave above. The reason to use Knockout (or any other MVVM library) is to make it easy to bind your views to a Model - a View Model - thus allowing you stop writing a lot of boilerplate code just to return values from your view.

I see a lot of wonky javascript/jquery code where people go and use something like this:

```
var ex = {
   some1: $('#textbox1').val(),
   some2: $('#textbox2').val()
};
```

The problem with this is that it is literally littered throughout the web application and it becomes extremely tedious to maintain. I know with Knockout, whenever my View is updated, my View Model will be updated as well.

It's not needed for every application, and you shouldn't use it just because it's whats "cool" to use. There obviously needs to be a reason to use it, my example above is one reason and im sure there are more.

Comment: What you're talking about is data binding. And that's what originally let me to knockout, but that's not the only way to do data binding. There's a jQuery plugin (http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-data-binding-templates-and-mobile-john-resig-at-fowa), for example, that allows very easy data binding without embedding that binding logic into the html.

Comment: Data-binding, like dom manipulation, templating, or dependency injection, are, it seems to me anyway, techniques or tools that aren't part of any specific pattern.

Comment: @nicholas Whether you are putting the html ids in the javascript with that library, or the javascript field names in the html with knockout, its kind of the same isn't it?  The power with MVVM isn't so much the data binding, but the behavior binding, when you get to having view state properties and not just data properties it allows for a much easier way to develop interactive screens.  But as stated above its not for every use case, just another tool in the toolbox.

Comment: Here is more on MVP (of which MVVM is a derivative pattern) as a design pattern by Martin Fowler: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html